# NPE after finishAffinity()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, activity-finish

I have this code:

```
Api.logout(() -> {
   //Do some work cleaning up

   ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this)
   startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class))
})
```

This code keeps throwing an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.android.server.am.TaskRecord com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.task' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivityAffinity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2709)
    at android.app.Activity.finishAffinity(Activity.java:4717)
    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(ActivityCompat.java:287)
    at my.app.api.Api.lambda$logout$0(Api.java:43)
    at my.app.MainActivity.performLogOut(MainActivity.java:90)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5261)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:734)
```

Looks like this bug lies in `ActivityCompat.finishAffinity` method.

What causes the bug and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, call the Intent then finish the Activity otherwise Activity Context will be null when calling the Intent.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class))
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this)
```

Comment: Your solution is not correct. The SignInActivity will be closed on finishAffinity call

Comment: Please see below answer. This is the correct answer since it is the actual problem that can cause this exception

Comment: 'Activity Context will be null when calling the Intent' Wrong. Activity IS the Context.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened when activity was already `finished` or `isFinishing`. I found only one solution:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy()
   // kill or unsubscribe your `Api` here
}
```

My code looked like that:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.some_activity)

    handler = Handler(mainLooper)
}

private fun someMethod() {
   handler.postDelayed({ finishAffinity() }, 10000)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
}
```